# Does Darwin (MacOS kernel) do memory overcommit?

Tags: mac-osx

For example, Linux has `vm.overcommit_memory` which is on by default. Windows does not have memory overcommit. Does MacOS? Is it configurable? What's the default setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested on my MacOS and it's working. I use code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750796/allocating-more-memory-than-there-exists-using-malloc). And system allow me allocate more then 40Gb memory, with only 16Gb RAM onboard and 6Gb used swap(on picture process of allocation before OOM-killer execution).

[image: Activity monitor]

My kernel version is:

```
Darwin AT-MacBook-Pro-2.local 16.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.5.0: Fri Mar  3 16:52:33 PST 2017; root:xnu-3789.51.2~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

I don't found possibility to configure overcommit, but look like by default it 2. But we should remember, that MacOS have dynamic swap and it [compress memory](https://www.lifewire.com/understanding-compressed-memory-os-x-2260327), so my assumption could be wrong.

Comment: What happens if you start writing data on the allocated area? Just writing one number (e.g. page counter) every 4 KB should require actual pages to be reserved and then you can see what really happens. On linux OOM Killer would step in and kill the process taking most RAM.

Comment: Can I overcommit on FreeBSD as well?

Comment: @Nick, yes you can.